# Magento 2.4 order confirmation email

Tags: magento2, order-confirmation-email

The order confirmation email was sent as shows in magento admin order page.
Reference image.
[image]

On the same order, it shows 'Customer Not Notified'.

Reference image.
[image]

How to fix this & what's the reason ?

Comment: you can check magento logs, if you don't find anything in logs then you can check email sender logs to check that is mail sending working or not

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to fix as these two things are not related. The order confirmation email was sent successfully and is totally separate from the order comments history. In your case the payment method added an order comment, this is just for your reference and the customer will not see it.

Each order comment will have its own 'Customer Notified' or 'Customer Not Notified' result. These can be created automatically by system generated events or manually by you.

If you want to leave a comment about the order that the customer will receive an additional notification about just add your comment and check the 'Notify Customer by Email' option before hitting 'Submit Comment'.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer !